# Using PowerShell Restart-Service cmdlet with a service that has an instance name

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, service

I want to restart a service on a remote machine using PowerShell. The service has both a displayname and an instancename. Can I use the Restart-Service cmdlet to do this? I don't see an instancename parameter, and I can't seem to make the "displayname$instancename" syntax work.

This syntax does not work:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Restart-Service -displayname 'DisplayName$InstanceName' -PassThru}
```

I thought at first the problem was the $ character, but I found that this syntax does work:

```
Get-Service 'displayname$instancename'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to single quotes in the first command.  The double quotes are preforming variable substitution.

Comment: I just tried with it with single quotes... no luck. I'll update my question to remove the double quotes.

Comment: He is saying use double quotes instead of single quotes.  If you use double quotes, it will substitute the value of a variable. If you use single quotes, it treats it just as a string of characters, without substituting values.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to restart services on remote systems.  You might need to add the `-credentials` tag if you don't have permissions.  This is really nice because it works on Server 2003/Windows XP boxes as well.

```
$Service = "InstanceNameOfService"
$Computer = "MyComputer"
$varService = Get-WmiObject -computername $Computer -class win32_service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $Service }
$varService.restartservice()
```